# What is javascript version of jquery's on() &trigger() (with ability to catch parameters)

Tags: javascript

I have checked all stackoverflow about javascript version version of jquery's on(). But none of them have the ability to catch parameters like real jquery's on().

In official jquery docs about .on() they support .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
But all javascript equivalent version i found only can do like this .on( events [, selector ], handler ). negleting the data attribute.

I have also checked all stackoverflow about javascript version version of jquery's trigger(). But none of them have the ability to pass parameters like real jquery's trigger().

In official jquery docs about .trigger() they support .trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )
But all javascript equivalent version i found only can do like this .trigger( event ). negleting the extraParameters attribute.

Please do not referencing the current js equivalent of .on & .trigger that you an find online. I have searched it for 3days. None of them can pass/receive parameters like jquery do.

So, what is vanilla javascript version jquery's trigger() & on() but with ability to pass and receive parameters. for example like this code:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function( event, parameters ) {
  alert( parameters.param1 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "click", [ { 'param1': true } ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a custom event with data using the following function:

```js
// See: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com
const triggerEvent = (el, eventName, data) => {
  let event;
  if (window.CustomEvent && typeof window.CustomEvent === 'function') {
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: data });
  } else {
    event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    event.initCustomEvent(eventName, true, true, data);
  }
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};

const
  fooEl = document.querySelector('#foo'),
  onClick = e => console.log(e.target, e.detail.param1);

fooEl.addEventListener('click', onClick);
triggerEvent(fooEl, 'click', { param1: true });
```

```html
<button id="foo">Foo</button>

<!--

$("#foo").on("click", function(event, parameters) {
  alert(parameters.param1);
});
$("#foo").trigger("click", [{
  'param1': true
}]);

-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function into `addEventListener` that takes the event parameter and passes on that parameter *and* whatever else you want to pass:

```js
const doSomething = (event, otherArg) => {
  console.log('Target:', event.target);
  console.log('otherArg:', otherArg);
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => doSomething(e, 'foobar'));
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Hi. thank you very much for answering. But its not quite i'm looking for. The purpose of the listener is to catch the parameter which passed from the trigger. In your example the listener act as both pass and catch of the parameter